# How to ignore this errors in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm writing google chrome extension, it's working, but Chrome show me errors and until I delete them extension doesn't work. How I can ignore them, or what I need to write in code? I tried to use 'if' or 'try'&'catch' but errors appear again and again. Usually error is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"
I have no idea to solve this issue
thank you

```
const phoneNumber= /(?:\+|\d)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d/g
const instagram=/(([Ii]nst?a?g?r?a?m?)|(ig)|<U\+1F606>):?[ ]?@?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm
const ig=/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm

function getInboxElements() {
    if (document.getElementById('messages-tab')!=null){ //an error appears here

    document.getElementById('messages-tab').click()
    return document.querySelectorAll(".messageListItem")
}}

function processInboxElements(messagesArray){
    for (let i = 0; i < messagesArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            (messagesArray[i].click());       //here too
            let messages=getMessages()
            let profileText=getProfileText()
            processProfileAndMessages(messages,profileText)
        }, [i] * 3000)
    }

}

function getProfileText() {
    if (document.querySelector(".BreakWord > div:nth-child(1)").innerText!=null){
    console.log(document.querySelector(".BreakWord > div:nth-child(1)").innerText)
    return document.querySelector(".BreakWord > div:nth-child(1)").innerText


}}

function getMessages(){
    const items=document.querySelectorAll('.msgHelper');
    let messagesArray=[]
    items.forEach(function(text){
        messagesArray.push(text.innerText)
    })
    return messagesArray
}


function parseText(text_info){

    matchPhone=text_info.match(phoneNumber)
    matchInstagram=text_info.match(instagram)
    matchInsta=text_info.match(ig)
    console.log(matchPhone)
    console.log(matchInsta)
    console.log(matchInstagram)
    let dataArray = [matchPhone, matchInsta, matchInstagram]
    // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: [matchPhone, matchInsta, matchInstagram] }, function(response) {
    //     console.log(response);
    // });
    sendData(dataArray)

}

async function sendData(dataArray) {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/boot2',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: dataArray

    }
)

}



function processProfileAndMessages(messagesArray, profileText){
    parseText(profileText)
    messagesArray.forEach(function (m) {
        parseText(m)

    })

}


let inboxElements=getInboxElements()
processInboxElements(inboxElements)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `.innerText` that is `null`, but the return value of `document.querySelector(…)` itself. You'll want

```
function getProfileText() {
    const element = document.querySelector(".BreakWord > div:nth-child(1)");
//  if (element.innerText != null) { - wrong
    if (element != null) { // right
        console.log(element.innerText);
        return element.innerText;
    }
}
```